# groovy fails install on OSX

Tags: ros, groovy-beta, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install Groovy on OSX using homebrew. I follow the instructions on the installation page. When I get to the cmake step, I get the following error:

```
$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/groovy -DSETUPTOOLS_DEV_LAYOUT=OFF
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /Users/jkp/groovy_underlay/build/devel
-- Found gtest: gtests will be built
-- catkin 0.5.58
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jkp/groovy_underlay/build/catkin_generated/generate_cached_env.py", line 12, in <module>
    from catkin.environment_cache import generate_environment_script, generate_static_environment_script
ImportError: No module named environment_cache
CMake Error at catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  execute_process(/usr/local/bin/python
  /Users/jkp/groovy_underlay/build/catkin_generated/generate_cached_env.py)
  returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  catkin/cmake/all.cmake:187 (safe_execute_process)
  CMakeLists.txt:15 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Is there something I have missed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50987/groovy-fails-install-on-osx/) by [jkp](https://answers.ros.org/users/3397/jkp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2012-12-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2012-12-23**:
It looks like the Python modules from catkin are not found. Can you please post line 11 (the one before the failing import) of the mentioned generate_cached_env.py file?

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2012-12-23**:
You can also try updating your version of catkin_pkg with `sudo pip install -U catkin_pkg`

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2012-12-23**:
Also I am going to be updating the instructions soon to reflect the new method of building ROS from source show here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Source

**Comment by [jkp](https://answers.ros.org/users/3397/jkp/) on 2012-12-25**:
Thanks for your comments. The update of catkin did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This can happen if you have the fuerte environment variables set. Just comment out the line in your .bashrc which sources the setup.bash (or whatever you have depending on your shell) and try the cmake step again (after opening a new terminal).

---

Originally posted by [kartikmohta](https://answers.ros.org/users/524/kartikmohta/) with karma: 308 on 2013-01-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2013-01-01**:
What is a `fuerte environment variable`?

**Comment by [kartikmohta](https://answers.ros.org/users/524/kartikmohta/) on 2013-01-01**:
I meant to say the ROS environment variables from a fuerte install, things like ROS_ROOT etc.

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2013-01-04**:
kartikmohta is correct. Make sure you don't have a fuerte environment sourced or that you don't have catkin installed to /usr/local or somewhere else on your python path. you can test this by opening python and ensuring that import catkin fails.